# What is Best practice to Move DATA FILES to GITHUB Repo

Tags: github

I am slightly new to github, So please bare if i'm asking very basic here.

I have a github repository. Where i have folder structures like below

```
company --> scripts --> python --> python_scripts.py
company --> inbound --> Data files
company --> outbound --> Data files
```

the size of my datafiles in inbound and outbound folders are ~2GB and it keeps increasing daily. What is the best practice to store data files in git repo.

Comment: Are these data files part of your source code, or are they files that your program operates on?

Comment: My programs operates on those data files

Answer (score 2):

You should not store these data files in your repository.  They are data that your programs operate on and are not part of the source code.  Adding them to your repository will just bloat the repository.

You should remove the directories in question with `git rm -r --cached DIRECTORY` and then add them to `.gitignore`.  You should then store them in some other location that's a better fit for data, like an artifact server or a cloud storage bucket, or just locally on the affected system.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use
Git Large File Storage (LFS),  see https://git-lfs.github.com/

Comment: my github is managed by my organization, I don't have access to install any plugins. Is it good idea to compress and load the data files to git repo.

Comment: "Git LFS is available for every repository on GitHub, whether or not your account or organization has a paid subscription." - https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/about-storage-and-bandwidth-usage